# UIActivityViewController Facebook/Twitter populate location

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to populate location in the twitter/facebook share sheet. I am able to populate the text and the image and the sharing works fine. How do I pre-populate the location field with a location I already have (lat/long).Is there any particular property or type that goes into the activity items array?

Thanks!